# How to setup correct path for VSCode Debug?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am developing an embedded application and currently working on setting up debugging in VisualStudioCode. The extension I am using is called `cortex-debug`.

**Problem:**
The vscode debug view shows only disassembly when it meets a breakpoint

**Problem overview:**

- The `.elf` file is located in `./build/product/`
- From debug symbols the `main.c` file is located in `../../src/`
- GDB console view correctly locates the line in `main.c` file
- VSCode cannot find file `../../src/main.c` because this relative path is pointing outside of the workspace.

**Filestructure**:

```
.
├── Repositories
│   ├── Workspace
│   │   ├── build
│   │   │   └── product
│   │   │       └── product.elf
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── main.c
│   └── src (*) //non-existent src directory outside of Workspace
│       └── main.c (*) //non-existent file that vscode is pointing to
[...]
```

**Debugger Configuration**:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to gdbserver",
            "servertype": "external",
            "gdbTarget": "localhost:2331",
            "gdbPath": "arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "preLaunchTask": "/*START THE DEBUG SERVER*/",
            "executable": "${workspaceFolder}/build/product/product.elf",
            "svdFile": "/*REDACTED*/",
            "runToMain": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output**:

- GDB console:

`Breakpoint 1, main () at ../../src/main.c:210 210     /*some code that matches the contents of the file` - which means it correctly finds the main.c file

- VSCode debugger:

`Unable to open 'main.c': Unable to read file '/home/username/Repositories/src/main.c' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/home/username/Repositories/src/main.c')`

**Possible Cause**:

- The current path of vscode debugger is set to `./build` or `./.vscode`.

How to make vscode find the correct path to the main.c file?

Comment: what is your build system?cmake? and what happens if you set `/home/username/Repositories/Workspace` for your `cwd` manually?

Comment: I am using WAF to build the whole project.
No change when setting the path manually.